# Safari not playing video in background, working on other browsers

Tags: video, safari, compatibility

I have a video as the background on a site I'm working on, and the background isn't working on Safari (desktop, not mobile). It's doing fine on Chrome, Firefox, IE 11, and Opera. I checked which types of videos Safari supported, and according to what Apple says, the file types and the HTML are valid. Here's what the video looks like in the code:

```
<div class="video-background">
    <video id="video" preload="none" poster="./index_files" autoplay="autoplay" loop="true">
        <source src="./index_files/Foo_cut_soundless_WEBM.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="./index_files/Foo_cut_soundless_MP4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Thanks!